# Qt Creator: Why Qt.labs.controls appear as red boxes?

Tags: qml, qt-creator, qt-designer

Why Qt.labs controls appear as red boxes on the Qt Creator Designer?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you see "Labs" in the name of a Qt module, it means it's not ready to be a proper module, as such. In the case of Qt Labs Controls, it was released as a tech preview in Qt 5.6. This means that the API is subject to change while it is refined into something considered worthy of being a Qt module.

The red boxes you see are just placeholder graphics, something not unusual for a tech preview. In Qt 5.7, the module is called Qt Quick Controls 2, and the actual icons should be available in Creator.